# Trying to conditionally sum some element in a dataframe, I obtain KeyError: "None of [Float64Index(...)] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, keyerror

I have a Dataframe, **df**

In a loop, each iteration I create a copy of this Dataframe, **temp_df**. It's almost the same, with a slight difference.

I have a Classification Model, **model**. The function **classification_results** returns an array of 0s and 1s, which tell me the predicted class for each element of **temp_df**

I want to take all the elements of **temp_df** which have predicted classes = 1, and to store the sum of the value in another columns for those exact elements.

The whole code is like this:

```
for c in range(number_of_iterations):
    temp_df = df.copy()
    temp_df["my_column"] = df.apply(lambda row: my_function(row, c), axis=1)
    results[c] = temp_df[classification_results(model, temp_df)].another_column.sum()
```

**Where:**

```
classification_results(model, temp_df)
```

returns something like:

```
array([1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0.])
```

**So I expect that:**

```
temp_df[classification_results(model, temp_df)]
```

returns a df with only a few elements from temp_df, like if I was doing something like:

```
temp_df[temp_df["a_column"] == Something]
```

**Instead, running my code I obtain:**

```
KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
...
1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
dtype='float64', length=761)] are in the [columns]"
```

I couldn't find an answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try: `results[c] = temp_df[classification_results(model, temp_df) == 1].another_column.sum()`

Comment: @Aryerez it works, you could post it directly as an answer

Comment: Not enough work for an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment of @Aryerez I replaced

```
temp_df[classification_results(model, temp_df)]
```

With

```
temp_df[classification_results(model, temp_df) == 1]
```

(it was fine also this:)

```
temp_df[classification_results(model, temp_df).astype(bool)]
```

Because you cannot use a float array (and not even an Int array, which surprises me) to filter the data in a DF